# use if (!num) to test typeof in javascript

Tags: javascript, typeof

I'm writing a function that needs to test if the argument passed is a number.  I'm a novice so I just wrote something like this:

```
if (typeof num !== "number") {
    return false;
}
```

I looked at someone else's code for the same purpose and they just had something like this:

```
if (!num) {
    return false;
}
```

I find this confusing.  If zero was passed to the function, wouldn't !num evaluate as true?  How does this second chunk of code robustly test the type of the num argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"If zero was passed to the function, wouldn't `!num` evaluate as true?"*

Yes it would, and also if `NaN` or any  falsey non-number value.

> *"How does this second chunk of code robustly test the type of the `num` argument?"*

It doesn't. It only tests the "falseyness" of the value. Every falsey value will give a `true` result to the `if` statement.

Those values are:

- `false`
- `""`
- `0`
- `NaN`
- `null`
- `undefined`

Any other value will fail the `if` condition.

*(Of course all this is reversed if you don't negate the value with `!`)*

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function: [isNaN(value)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the second statement not validating properly whether the input is number or not. You might as well improve you check like this:

> if ((typeof(num) !== "number) || (isNaN(num) || (!isFinite(num) {
>
> > ```
> >     return false;
> > ```
> >
> > }

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that is not a valid line of code. [Here Is Test](http://jsfiddle.net/CrvNV/)
Correct code would be:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

as describe in [This ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/174921#174921)